# How can I build Rust code with a C++/Qt/CMake project?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, rust

I have an existing C++/Qt [project](http://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice) built with CMake. I'd like to start adding Rust code which I can invoke from inside the main C++ codebase.

What's the right way to structure the project?

Current project structure:

```
./CMakeLists.txt
./subproject-foo/CMakeLists.txt
./subproject-foo/src/...
./subproject-bar/CmakeLists.txt
./subproject-bar/src/...
./common/CMakeLists.txt
./common/src/...
```

I'd like to add a `common-rust/...` directory with similar structure.

How can I incorporate this into the project?

Comment: Are you able to use `cargo`? If so, I'd suggest just having rules that call out to Cargo.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use the [`ExternalProject` module](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/ExternalProject.html) for this.  It's designed to allow building of external dependencies - even ones which don't use CMake.  Here's a [useful article](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html) on using it.

So say you have your "common-rust" subdirectory and its Cargo.toml contains:

```
[package]
name = "rust_example"
version = "0.1.0"

[lib]
name = "rust_example"
crate-type = ["staticlib"]
```

and it exposes a function `add` via its lib.rs:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn add(lhs: u32, rhs: u32) -> u32 {
    lhs + rhs
}
```

Then your top-level CMakeLists.txt could look something like this:

```
add_executable(Example cpp/main.cpp)

# Enable ExternalProject CMake module
include(ExternalProject)

# Set default ExternalProject root directory
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES EP_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Rust)

# Add rust_example as a CMake target
ExternalProject_Add(
    rust_example
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND cargo build COMMAND cargo build --release
    BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common-rust"
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_BUILD ON)

# Create dependency of Example on rust_example
add_dependencies(Example rust_example)

# Specify Example's link libraries
target_link_libraries(Example
    debug "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common-rust/target/debug/librust_example.a"
    optimized "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common-rust/target/release/librust_example.a"
    ws2_32 userenv advapi32)

set_target_properties(Example PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 11 CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

When you build the Rust target as a `staticlib` it outputs which other libraries should be linked.  I've only tried this on Windows, hence `ws2_32`, `userenv`, and `advapi32` are linked.  This won't be cross-platform obviously, but you can handle that easily enough (e.g. set a variable to the list of dependencies appropriate to each platform inside an `if..else` block and append that in the `target_link_libraries` call).

Also note that this depends on Cargo being available in the path.

You should be good to go now.  The file "cpp/main.cpp" could contain something like:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
  uint32_t add(uint32_t lhs, uint32_t rhs);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "1300 + 14 == " << add(1300, 14) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Here's a link to a working [example project](https://gitlab.com/Fraser999/Rust-From-CXX/tree/master).

Comment: Wow, what a comprehensive answer. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yeah - no worries.  It was an interesting question and I wanted to see how it would work :)

Comment: If you are building on platforms other than Windows, you'll need to change the system link libraries `ws2_32 userenv advapi32` to something else. For example, on macOS you need: `m c System resolv`.

Comment: Hi @Fraser, I am facing error generating librust_example.a file.
[build] [ 80%] Built target rust_example
[build] mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No rule to make target 'C:/Workspace/RustRepowc/rust_projects/Rust-From-CXX-master/common-rust/target/debug/librust_example.a', needed by 'Example.exe'.  Stop.

Answer (score 8):

There is now a project that can be used to build: Corrosion https://github.com/corrosion-rs/corrosion

So your CMakeLists.txt would just have this:

```
# See the Corrosion README to find more ways to get Corrosion
find_package(Corrosion REQUIRED)

corrosion_import_crate(MANIFEST_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common-rust)
```